# Can I keep the shell scripts inside the java project

Tags: java, shell

I want to run some shell scripts from java code. I am using jsch library which copies the shell script to a remote machine and executes that code.

Now the question, can I maintain these shell scripts inside the java project?
what are the advantages/disadvantages, if I maintain it separately in a different project.

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: I would manage them in same project, you will have all things in the same place, same repository, etc. it will be more compact. I dont know how complex they are...

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? The existing answers seam to interpred as " projects of the IDE". More interesting could be the question whether to bundle the scripts into the JAR of the Application.

Comment: My question was related to whether to bundle the scripts in the same war/jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it depends on the use case with no clear advantage/disadvantage.

1. If used by only that Java project them keep them in the same project.

   **"Advantage":** Easier to maintain, no need to pull in external dependencies.

   **Side Effect:** Limits their use. i.e. can't use them in other projects easily.
2. If the scripts are used by other projects then make them an external dependency.

   **"Advantage":** Easier to synchronise with all the projects using them.

   **Side Effect:** You have to pull them in as an external dependency. Which is not even a problem if you using maven or ant.